# Buckminster 3.6 and above on Jenkins, limited error feedback

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, buckminster

I was trying to find an answer for my problem for a long time, but I wasn't able to.
We are using Jenkins 1.501 with Buckminster plug-in 1.1.0. Some time ago I had to move from Buckminster 3.5 to 3.6 but I encountered an important issue since then.
Basically if something goes wrong, I don't get details about problem and it happens also on higher versions of Buckminster e.g. 4.2.
The 3.5 was already installed when I joined the company, so I am not sure if it was modified in any way (I couldn't find it), as it points to a directory.
I think the target platform used (custom) is 3.6.2 (eclipse).

Example: when developer makes a mistake and add new plug-in to project (it is used then by other bundles), but forgot to add it to features configuration, build fails.
However Buckminster plug-in doesn't tell you anything useful why. The exception is very general Java exception which points back to xml file line from build step.
When I was using 3.5, it was telling me exactly what went wrong (e.g. can't find reference to given plug-in id). It happens for some other cases too.

Anyone has an idea what do I need to change?

Comment: Did you set logging level in Jenkins job for Buckminster plugin? Like here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/37749187/TP-config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1249308260000. You can set different log levels in that combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I was told by Lorenzo Bettini (he takes care of Buckminster plug-in) that there is a bug and ANT log level is not set from 3.6 version. This setting is different than Buckminster logging (but they meant to be connected).

In version 3.7 and above it is possible to set ANT log level.

Steps to fix issue:
1) Update the build configuration to use Buckminster 3.7 (or any above if needed)
2) In advanced options for Buckminster build step add ‘--loglevel ant=debug’ in 'Equinox Launcher Arguments' field.

Only 'debug' options gives information needed (usually printed out at the end).

Unfortunately I am not allowed to add a picture yet.